# Atlas Search by regex

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

What is the best way to do full text search using Atlas?
For example, I put **mike@** and I want to see **da.mike@gmail.com** **mike@gmail.com** ...
But not something like **mikke@... mmike@...**, such a result can show a search using autocomplete.
As I understood, most likely I need to use regex

```
{
    "$search": {
        "index": "free-text",

        {
            "regex": {
                "path": "email",
                "query": ".*mike@.*",
            },
        },

    },
}
```

Before that I created search index:

```
"email": [{
        "tokenization": "nGram",
        "type": "autocomplete"
    },
    {
        "analyzer": "lucene.keyword",
        "type": "string"
    }
]
```

It works almost good, but it is a case-sensitive, and I can't find out how to send it as insensitive
So,
**1. Is there a better way how to build such a search?**

**2. if so, how to do a regex search insensitive to the case?**

Thank you a lot for helping, guys!

Tru to create an index with autocomplete type, and build query as a phrase, regex, autocomplete, but the result was not good.

Answer (score 1):

For your email you can use a email-specific tokenizer: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/analyzers/tokenizers/#uaxurlemail

And then I'd recommend using a different analyzer instead of keyword to get case-insensitive. Check out this [webtool](https://www.atlassearchindexes.com/) to play around with the options (there's an email example in there)

Comment: There is also a name field, mention it only for example